# Why Eclipse tells me that my project target API level is 7?

Tags: android, eclipse

I right click on the project and choose Android 5.0 under "Project Build Target".
Should I do something else also ?

Comment: Where and how does Eclipse tell you that your "project target API level is 7"?

Comment: For example in the warning Description Resource Path Location Type
Attribute minSdkVersion (8) is higher than the project target API level (7) AndroidManifest.xml /OpenCV Sample - image-manipulations line 1 Android ADT Problem

Comment: This is an imported project by the way, not mine.

Comment: check Imported project's project.properties file and set API Level there too.

Comment: The Project you have imported uses some features(eg, Classes or functions) that are supported from Api level 8 onwards. But in your AndroidManifest.xml android:minSdkVersion="7", hence the error/warning.  Modify it to android:minSdkVersion="8". Or you can find which feature is supported from level 8 onward, and use an alternatity for it that has backward Api support.

Answer (score 2):

Here, what it is referring to is your `android:minSdkVersion`, found in the `<uses-sdk>` element in your manifest.